# How to get value of the button pressed by using onclick in HTML. I have 6 buttons with same class name but different values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays

I want to get value of the button pressed. I have 6 buttons as folllows:

```html
<button class="theme" value="100" onclick="buytheme()">Points:100</button>
<button class="theme" value="200" onclick="buytheme()">Points:200</button>
<button class="theme" value="300" onclick="buytheme()">Points:300</button>
<button class="theme" value="400" onclick="buytheme()">Points:400</button>
<button class="theme" value="500" onclick="buytheme()">Points:500</button>
<button class="theme" value="600" onclick="buytheme()">Points:600</button>
```

Following is my JS function:

```js
function buytheme(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("theme");
}
```

I have also tried:

```js
const pbtn=document.querySelectorAll("button.theme");
for(var i=0;i<pbtn.length;i++){
    (pbtn[i].onclick)=()=>{
        console.log(pbtn[0].value);
    }
}
```

But none of following seems to work. Please help me how to get exact value of the button I press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look over all of the elements with the class name `theme` and add a `addEventListener` to all of them, and log it's value.

```
<button class="theme" value="100">Points:100</button>
<button class="theme" value="200">Points:200</button>
<button class="theme" value="300">Points:300</button>
<button class="theme" value="400">Points:400</button>
<button class="theme" value="500">Points:500</button>
<button class="theme" value="600">Points:600</button>

<script lang="js">
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("theme");
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            const value = this.value;
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: but now the "value" is inside the function, how can i use it outside the function? even if it is intialized outside the function it's value can only be changed for inside of the function. is there any way i can get value outside this function?

Comment: You can pass the value to another function and execute your code there. Why do you need the value outside of the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `event listeners` and `e.target.value` to resolve this,

```
<button class="theme" value="100">Points:100</button>
<button class="theme" value="200">Points:200</button>
<button class="theme" value="300">Points:300</button>
<button class="theme" value="400">Points:400</button>
<button class="theme" value="500">Points:500</button>
<button class="theme" value="600">Points:600</button>
<script lang="js">
    document.querySelectorAll('.theme').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            console.log(event.target.value);
        })
    })
</script>
```